# Show that unimodular matrices form a group in complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mathematical-physics, complex-geometry

Unimodular transformation are linear transformation of the form w2'=aw2-bw1
And w1'= cw2-dw1 with integ coefficients and determinant=±1
Now how to prove unimodular matrices form a group??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.